# How can I create custom script in DTM for click and display in a single rule?

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-analytics

I have 2 id 1. show_ocancel_popup and 2. cancel_order_button, first one is for a notification which comes on a click of cancel button and 2nd one is for confirmation button, I am triggering a rule which will fire on either appearance of 1st id or on click of 2nd id. How can I create a custom script to handle this in a single rule?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to your question.

Comment: Do let me know what additional details are required.

Answer (score 1):

If clicking on the cancel button always shows the notification popup, then maybe it's okay to assume clicking on the cancel button is effectively the same as viewing the notification for it.

If that's good enough for you, then you can you can setup a single **Event Based Rule**

**Event Type** `click`

**Element Tag or Selector**

`#show_ocancel_popup,#cancel_order_button`

[image]

If you need to know which button was clicked, you can use `this` in the various code boxes in the rule (as long as the code box is not flagged to execute globally).

**One random example:**

If you want to push the button's `id` to an Adobe Analytics prop, you can use `%this.id%` in the field:

[image]

Or by adding it via the Adobe Analytics custom code box instead:

```
s.linkTrackVars=s.linkTrackVars||'';
s.linkTrackVars+=',prop8';
s.prop8 = this.id;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case, there are 2 cases in 1st, only notification  will appear and in 2nd the #cancel_order_button will be available to click for the user. So here is the tricky part, in case the 1st case happen there will be no further click but in 2nd case there will be another click on notification.
Hope this clarifies the problem.